# image not displaying on device or in simulator (Xcode)

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am creating a basic app in Xcode the  graphics were designed in photoshop and exported as .png files

The first image worked fine but the second image (very similar to first does not show up)

Would appreciate any help with this

Comment: Could you explain more? I think you should take a screen shot for everyone to easy to see

Comment: How are you adding the images? Are they placed in the interface builder, or are they in code: [UIImage imageWithURL:]?

Comment: in the interface builder using a UImageView

Comment: unfortunately i cannot add a screenshot as the information is confidential

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i solved it myself.

For anybody wondering I just added the .png file manually to the copy bundle resources in build phases

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this same problem, I solve it turning off Auto-Layout and positioning the imageview by the code `self.imageview.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,with,height);`, aslo add the image by the code to prevent any issue `self.imageview.image = [UIImage imagenamed:@"image.png"];` and ready!

Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you i will try this, the app has since had other problems.. so will need to fix that first...